# Intellisense configuration for multiple builds

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a project that has 3 different build configurations. One is for unit testing on x86, one is for unit testing on arm and one is the normal project build for our arm target.
The problem is, that Intellisense does not automatically detect the source files for all those configs, it mostly works fine for the normal build, but for the tests I need to create a compile_commands.json using cmake and then point intellisense to that.
But when developing and writing unit tests, its pretty annoying to always switch out the compile_commands.json before writing any code. Is there any better solution to this? Am I missing something?

I tried using build_commands.json and I tried by setting the includePath/browse.path variables.
the includepath variant did not work at all for me, it had no effect, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: why not create CMake presets for each "configuration"? Then you can easily switch between them. the CMake Tools extension will help you out with that.

Comment: what do you mean by Presets? and switching between cmake presets wont do anything to intellisense or will it?

Comment: also I have to add that I need to restart vscode every hour or so, otherwise intellisense somehow stops working after some time

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you define a set of [CMake Presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) for each of your "configurations". The CMake Tools extension [has support for CMake Presets](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-presets.md), and will make it pretty easy for you to switch between them, getting proper IntelliSense and build for whichever one is currently selected.